# Inline JavaScript transition from negative position overridden by CSS style

Tags: javascript, css

I have a [fiddle that has two small boxes inside a larger box](https://jsfiddle.net/7d94ytmq/3/).

When either of the buttons "Run B" or "Run C" is clicked, the corresponding box is run through a CSS transition, effected via JavaScript. The code is reproduced here with comments:

```
  // Get the specified box
  var element = document.getElementById(id);

  // Save initial style for resetting
  var initial = element.style.cssText;

  // Initialise transition
  element.style.position = 'relative';
  element.style.transition = 'top 800ms ease';

  // Set start position
  element.style.top = '-50px';

  // Effect the transition in the next cycle
  // by setting the end position
  setTimeout(function(){

    element.style.top = '15px';

  }, 25);

// Reset the style on completion
setTimeout(function(){

    element.style.cssText = initial;
}, 800);
```

You should be able to observe that each transition is quite different. However, the only difference between the two boxes is the CSS property `top: 0` set in the stylesheet.

Can someone please explain why the transitions are different?

Since the style for the element is set inline, I would have expected that to override the CSS style, but that is not happening. Why does the `top: 0` have any impact at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll do my best to explain:
You are setting the top to `-50px` and then you have a `setTimeout` which sets it to `15px`;

Since `#b` have a starting position of `0px`, it will start animating to `-50px` but after 25 mllis it will get a new position of `15px` and it will animate there instead (you can see that if you give the first setTimeout a longer time like 100). Since 25 millis is very short, it looks like it immediately starts to go down.

Since `#c` does not have a starting position, when you set it to `-50` you actually give it a starting position and then it animates from -50 to 15px;

I hope I've managed to clarify it :)

Comment: The order doesn't matter. Beside that, it doesn't explain why `#b` and `#c` are not animating to `-50px`.

Comment: @NiZa - you're right, don't know why i thought it would, anyway, I've updated my answer

Comment: I think this could be the right explanation now. ;)

Comment: @fatman The statement "`#b` has a starting position of `0px`" is not quite correct. The starting position is set for both elements in code: `element.style.top = '-50px';`. This is an inline style and should override anything set in the CSS stylesheet.

Comment: read carefully, it has a starting position so it starts animating from 0 to -50px, then you set it after 25 millis to 15px so it changes direction and animates down (again, try giving it a larget timeout like 100 and you'll see), on the other hand #c doesn't have starting position so it imiidiatley jump to -50px and then start animating to 15px;

Comment: Yes, you're absolutely right. I was actually trying to reproduce a cross-browser issue (Edge was failing to animate `top` for a `div`), but it looks like this is correct behaviour and the problem lies elsewhere. Thanks.